# How to use javascript document.createElement, document.body, $(document) in HTML Webresouce as per Microsoft CRM Code Review?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamics-crm-online

First of all, I am not regular blogger and I am damn confuse. Please guide me if my question is not up to the mark. I will try to improve.

I have submitted a Microsoft CRM PlugIn of Microsoft Code Review. I am new in Javascript. I got few suggestion from their side specially in Java Script.

Some of them are following. Can any body please guide me? That will be greatly helpful:

1- Microsoft Comments: 'document.createElement('script')' calls a document object function of the CRM document object model (DOM) directly. This technique is unsupported in all versions of Dynamics CRM. Remove or replace with a supported API provided in the Xrm.Page client object model.
- Comments: 'document.body' calls a document object property of the CRM document object model (DOM) directly. This technique is unsupported in all versions of Dynamics CRM. Remove or replace with a supported API provided in the Xrm.Page client object model.

My code in .JS (as webresouce) file:

```
var NewScript = document.createElement('script')
NewScript.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"
document.body.appendChild(NewScript);
```

2- Microsoft Comments: '$(document)' calls a global DOM-related function of the CRM document object model (DOM) directly. This technique is unsupported in all versions of Dynamics CRM. Remove or replace with a supported API provided in the Xrm.Page client object model.

My code in .HTML (as webresource) file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //code
    }
</script>
```

3- Microsoft Comments: '$('#btnsave')' calls a global DOM-related function of the CRM document object model (DOM) directly. This technique is unsupported in all versions of Dynamics CRM. Remove or replace with a supported API provided in the Xrm.Page client object model.

My code in .HTML (as webresource) file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableButton() {
        $('#btnsave').attr('disabled', false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your post is quite confusing. You're not dealing with `Plugins` which are developed using C# for CRM. Instead it seems like you are working with client-side code (JavaScript)

**Regarding Point 1: Injecting jQuery**

As stated, using `appendChild` isn't supported in CRM online. In this instance you should probably include jQuery as a CRM web resource. You can then add this as a dependency on your form via the Form Properties dialog

**Regarding Point 2: Document OnReady**

`document.onReady` isn't required. Instead you should trigger your event from the form events in CRM.

1. Edit your form
2. Click Form Properties
3. Switch to Events tab
4. Add your JavaScript web resource to the Form Libraries
5. In the Event Handlers section, set the Control to Form and the Event to Onload
6. Add your web resource and give it the function name to execute

**Regarding Point 3 - Disabling Controls**

Regarding the second point, you shouldn't disable fields by accessing the DOM elements (e.g. `$("#btsave")`) although it is not clear what you are trying to disable, because there aren't any CRM elements with that ID.

The supported method of disabling a CRM Form Field is using the `XRM` JavaScript namespace. For example: `Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).setDisabled(bool)`